# FaunaDB update(append, remove) in already existing array

Tags: javascript, node.js, faunadb

Is there a way to update an array without getting the whole array, like it can be done in Firestore,

```
db.collection(COL).doc(DOC).update({
 data: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(DATA)
})
```

The code above but in FaunaDB

I will be using this in a react native application

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

You can use `Select` to extract a single array item. You can use `Append`, `Filter`, `Prepend`, and `Take` to perform some simple array modifications that might do the trick in specific cases, but there's no "replace item at index" capability, currently.

You could certainly write a UDF that uses `Take` and `Reverse` to access everything before and after a specific index, and then `Append` to put them in the correct sequence.

Comment: Do you know a noSQL DB(which is not firebase) that allows operation on arrays like that and has a like 10MB max document size ?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not familiar with the array manipulation capabilities of other noSQL databases.